# Saving currency textbox values in C#

Tags: c#

I had this class for currency textbox which I downloaded.

The code works fine when I enter values in the currency textbox. But when I try to execute my insert query from a stored procedure, this error appears:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to decimal.

I don't where the error is.

This is the code for the class currency textbox;

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Globalization;

namespace SSFASys
{
    public partial class currencytextbox:TextBox
    {
        readonly CultureInfo _ci = CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture;
        private readonly string _allowedCharacterSet;
        private readonly char _decimalSeparator;

        public currencytextbox()
        {
            var nf = new CultureInfo(_ci.Name, false).NumberFormat;
            _decimalSeparator = nf.CurrencyDecimalSeparator.ToCharArray()[0];
            _allowedCharacterSet = string.Format("0123456789{0}", _decimalSeparator);

            InitializeComponent();
        }
        /// Return Currency Text with No Formatting
        public string TextNoFormatting
        {
            get { return TypedText(); }
        }

        protected override void OnLeave(EventArgs e)
        {
            decimal amount;
            Text = decimal.TryParse(Text, NumberStyles.Currency, null, 
            out amount) ? amount.ToString("N") : 0.ToString("N");
            base.OnLeave(e);
        }

        private string TypedText()
        {
            var sonuc = string.Empty;
            return Text.Trim().Where(ch => _allowedCharacterSet.Contains(ch)).Aggregate
            (sonuc, (current, ch) => current + ch);
        }

        protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e)
        {     
            Text = TypedText();
            base.OnEnter(e);
        }

        protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && 
            e.KeyChar != _decimalSeparator && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            base.OnKeyPress(e);
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // currencytextbox
            // 
            this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Consolas", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }
    }
}
```

and this is my stored procedure for inserting the value of the currency textbox;

```
private void scholarshipinputs()
        {
            if (cmbclass.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please fill-in required CLASSIFICATION OF SCHOLARSHIP to proceed.");

            else if (currencytextboxamount.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please indicate a specific AMOUNT GRANTED for this SCHOLARSHIP PROGRAM to proceed.");
            }
            else if (cmbclass.Text == string.Empty && cmbtype.Text == string.Empty && cmbcode.Text == string.Empty && cmbdesc.Text == string.Empty && cmbterm.Text == string.Empty && currencytextboxamount.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please fill-in all required fields to proceed.");
            }
            else
            {
                sqlcon.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "insertssfapsdetails";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Connection = sqlcon;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ssfaptype", ssfaptype));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ssfapsclass", ssfapclass));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@amount", currencytextboxamount.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ssfapscode", cmbcode.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ssfapsdesc", cmbdesc.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@term", cmbterm.Text));
                int rowsaffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (rowsaffected > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Scholarship program successfully included for the term.");
                    cmbclass.Refresh();
                    cmbtype.Refresh();
                    cmbcode.Text = "";
                    cmbdesc.Text = "";
                    cmbterm.Text = "";
                    currencytextboxamount.Text = "";
                }
                else 
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No scholarship program included for the term. Please contact your system administrator to fix the problem.");
                }
                sqlcon.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: your database stores nvarchar which is text like string.
when you get that out of the database you get a string like "50.30" or "50,30" but thats text not a decimal. you need to convert that

Comment: What is your database schema? is amount decimal or nvarchar?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: my currency textbox is formatted as numeric or accounting format like "6,000.00" as it is displayed in the currency textbox when we type numbers within it. Is it possible to convert "6,000.00" as numeric? and if possible, can you give an idea/or sample code if any on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

your error should be here:

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ssfapsclass", ssfapclass));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@amount", currencytextboxamount.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ssfapscode", cmbcode.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ssfapsdesc", cmbdesc.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@term", cmbterm.Text));
```

you are trying to write text into a decimal field in the database, not sure which parameter it is (propably amount) but you need to convert it to decimal first

not directly related to the question:
you should use

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

}
```

with this your connection will be closed even if the programm throws an exception which you are not handling currently